# Mimic browser TLS fingerprint in node websocket

Tags: node.js, go, websocket, tls1.2, spoofing

How can I get a TLS/JA3 fingerprint, which mimics a major browser, in a websocket connection from node? Can I achieve this by modifying node’s TLS configuration, or do I need something more complex?
I've already tried passing shuffled ciphers as one of the options, along with the headers, using node.JS's ws library, however this wasn't enough achieve the desired effect.

Some libraries allow for single HTTP requests, e.g. [this one](https://github.com/zedd3v/mytls) written in the go language, but I need an open websocket connection.

Answer (score 0):

The JA3 fingerprint is based on ciphers and order and various TLS extensions and order. While ciphers and order can be changed, features like the TLS extension order are not accessible from node - I don't think there is even a OpenSSL API for this (OpenSSL is the TLS library underlying node). This means there is no way to emulate a specific JA3 fingerprint from node.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the curl-impersonate project to replace the underlying libcurl, which mimics browsers' tls and http2 fingerprints.